# custom marker flutter google maps

Tags: flutter, dart, google-maps

How do I make a marker like this? [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LRrOm.png)

I want to place markers like the ones shown in the picture as an icon on a map, and the image inside the location marker is from the Internet,  how can I do that?
I want an easy and quick way because I am a beginner

```
 return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text("Explore"),
  ),
  body: Container(
    child: GetBuilder<ExpoloreController>(
      builder: (controllerpage) => HandlingDataView(
        statusRequest: controllerpage.statusRequest,
        widget: controllerpage.kGooglePlex != null
            ? Container(
                width: double.infinity,
                height: double.infinity,
                child: GoogleMap(
                  myLocationButtonEnabled: true,
                  myLocationEnabled: true,
                  circles: controllerpage.circles,
                  markers: {
                    ...List.generate(
                      doctorsController.doctors.length,
                      (index) => Marker(
                        markerId: MarkerId(index.toString()),
                        position: LatLng(
                          double.tryParse(doctorsController.doctors[index]
                                  ["latitude"]) ??
                              33.31524,
                          double.tryParse(doctorsController.doctors[index]
                                  ["longitude"]) ??
                              44.3660667,
                        ),
                        infoWindow: InfoWindow(
                          title: doctorsController.doctors[index]["name"],
                        ),
                        icon: BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarkerWithHue(
                            BitmapDescriptor.hueBlue),
                        onTap: () {},
                      ),
                    ),
                  },
                  mapType: MapType.normal,
                  initialCameraPosition: controllerpage.kGooglePlex!,
                  onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controllermap) {
                    controllerpage.completercontroller!
                        .complete(controllermap);
                  },
                ),
              )
            : Container(),
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

Comment: You can try: https://pub.dev/packages/widget_to_marker

Comment: I agree with @Aks - using that package would be the easiest. If you were to do it manually you could read in image data, but you would need some way of turning a custom widget into an image, which the package handles for you.

Comment: To do that without using the package you can look into the github repository of widget_to_marker package. The code is not so hard to understand and just one file, and you can do the same with widget_to_image package to create image from custom widget

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this function:

```
Set<Marker> _createMarkers() {
Set<Marker> markers = Set<Marker>();
for (ShipLocation shipLocation in shipLocations) {
  BitmapDescriptor.fromAssetImage(
    ImageConfiguration(size: Size(48, 48)), // Adjust the size as needed
    'lib/assets/images/bg13.png',
  ).then((bitmapDescriptor) {
    markers.add(
      Marker(
        markerId: MarkerId(shipLocation.shipCode),
        icon: bitmapDescriptor,
        position: LatLng(shipLocation.location.latitude, shipLocation.location.longitude),
        onTap: () => _onMarkerTapped(
          shipLocation.shipCode,
          shipLocation.captain,
          shipLocation.location,
          shipLocation.time,
        ),
      ),
    );
  });
}
return markers;
```

}